# Referential transparency in Types in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Please have a look at this code ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glgEwgOwDwBUA0V0GUB8UAvDrlBAB7AoIDOUA2gLpQD8UyEAbhAE5QAuAFBRRY8RIl5yVGvQZxkAMz5QAGtgB02gBSKV-NbgCUTEZIuXR7HehnVkddW2cDYiFBmxH8x81YCxN04eXgBuIVBIHHAIWnQAVzAAG2gSBmQEgFsAIz5sWmBeRQBzJgio6HRY%20hJqyHik1IzsvN5yyNj3JGQAOVwMQhJ4Hq8YhsSUiHwIoQBjZIBDWnoAMQBxAHtNhAx7OXG47BhibpR%20wcIAb38oOc3kQt4EueBN3h1gNxhsJTcdAD632MxEIMBBVwAvkJoQtlmstjsAExjE7DDx9AbofDXW73R5FF5vD5fWC-f5A2AgohgiHQ2FLFZQVYAIUWuzslAcTnqcVx4nxTyJ70%203wxF2x5KggLFPQlvlBZ0xgzpMPmjLWbIQKOxUBuAoeQteItJI3OWPwUplSvl1LB4otquhnWiAHkANKnM3KzK5VQAHygT1KMyEQk4AHdmYiEDoAGzYCiKpMAaigSOMYUCAHps9Htrtg8gSlBA762thy3x8OGIFGNgWkfHE8moGmM1mrLn88jUAlkABrZCbCPISutau1%20ta5tQJM0udt9OZwJQbus9moIslssT3g1yPMrVNhOLhep5edrt5jfavuD4ejg91o-slFx-Cz%20eEC8dyzr49UA-IQgA)):

```js
type Widen<T, TS> = TS extends [] ? never :
                    TS extends [infer X, ...(infer XS)]
                        ? (T extends X ? X : Widen<T, XS>)
                        : never;
type TypesTuple = [number, string];
type Types = TypesTuple[number];
type WidenNS<T> = Widen<T, TypesTuple>;

class FGood<T extends Types, W = WidenNS<T>> {
    constructor(t: W, f: (_: W) => W) {}
}
class FGood2<T, W = WidenNS<T>> {
    constructor(t: W, f: (_: W) => W) {}
}
class FBad<T extends Types> {
    constructor(t: WidenNS<T>, f: (_: WidenNS<T>) => WidenNS<T>) {}
}
class FBad2<T> {
    constructor(t: WidenNS<T>, f: (_: WidenNS<T>) => WidenNS<T>) {}
}

type OK = WidenNS<number | string>;

new FGood(6, x => x + 2);           // FGood<string | number, number>
new FGood2(6, x => x + 2);          // FGood2<unknown, number>
new FBad(6, x => x + 2);            // FBad<string | number>
new FBad2(6, x => x + 2);           // FBad2<unknown>
new FBad2<6>(6, x => x + 2);        // FBad2<6>
```

I use Widen to convert `6` into `number`, i.e. literals into more general types.

The difference in behavior between `FGood` and `FBad` is surprising to me since it breaks referential transparency.

Also, why is `T` equal to `unknown` in `FGood2` and `FBad2`? I think that `unknown` causes `T` to be `number | string` instead of just `number` in `FGood` and `FBad`.

Evidently, I have no idea how TS does type inference.

I hope someone can shed some light on this issue! In the end I got it working, but I'd like to know why it works.